# AWS Gateway: Setting up a reverse-proxy to whitelist a slack API connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, slack-api

So a developer has created a Slack API request which connects to a server on port 5000 and I want to be able to setup a security group to allow the port to open to that specific API request.

The issue is Slack is hosted on AWS so the only option if I did not want to open port 5000 to everything is to allow the AWS regions.

The other option is from what I understand is setting up a reverse proxy on AWS Gateway to allow then whitelist through there. I am not sure how this is done and can not seem to find any reference material on this.

Comment: Are you running your own open source slack?

Comment: I do not think so

Comment: your question is not clear pls

Comment: what part of the question isnt clear?

Comment: you do not need to allow public traffic on port `5000` just whitelist slack IPs `13.224.32.156      (server-13-224-32-156.yto50.r.cloudfront.net) used on 16 August 2019
13.225.197.153      (server-13-225-197-153.yul62.r.cloudfront.net) used on 15 August 2019
52.84.138.56      (server-52-84-138-56.yto50.r.cloudfront.net) used on 11 August 2019
13.225.226.153      (13.225.226.153) used on 31 July 2019` https://myip.ms/info/whois/13.224.32.156/k/892701948/website/slack.com

Comment: Not really a long term solution if the IP changes that often

Comment: No, you are not the only one, Billion of people depend on their solution. And I am using the same for bitbucket from last two year.